# How can I integrate the given formula symbolically?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, symbolic-integration

[image: Formula: integrate [epsilon, epsilon(z=0)...epsilon(z)]]

Regarding the expression on the right of the equals sign, I defined the constants and trie dto integrate from 0 to z. But int returned an unresolved integral. How should I proceed to receive the expression epsilon(z)?

```
syms M epsilon C z
f=M.^2*sin(epsilon)/(sin(epsilon).^3-(sin(epsilon).^6-M^2*(1-(2*C/M*sin(epsilon).^3))).^0.5)
int(f,epsilon,0,z)
ans =
int((M^2*sin(epsilon))/(sin(epsilon)^3 - (sin(epsilon)^6 + M^2*((2*C*sin(epsilon)^3)/M -1))^(1/2)), epsilon, 0, z)
```

Thanks, Elisabeth

Comment: Can Matlab integrate from zero to a variable? I don't think so, but you can do this workaround. Try to calculate the indefinite integral with respect to the epsilon variable. It will result in some function that I call A. Your original integral should be equal to A(z) - A(0) (in the firs case simply epsilon in the integrated function becomes z). If matlab can't do the undefined integral either, the problem is in the function.